# running 2 while True loops at once

Tags: python, loops

I've recently started programming and I'm a little stuck on this program i'm trying to write.

essentially I need 2 while True loops playing at once but for some reason it plays the first loop once and then goes straight to the second.
Heres my code:

```
import keyboard
import time


while True:   
        keyboard.write("t") 
        time.sleep(0.25)  
                    


        while True:
            keyboard.write("s")
            keyboard.write("e")
            time.sleep(0.50)
```

So it's meant to press the 'T' Key every 0.25 seconds and the 'S + E' keys every 0.5 seconds all at the same time.

I've tried searching online for examples of similar programs that use loops and keyboards but to no luck.

Any guidance would be really appreciated

Comment: Your code does not run it together, it runs a while loop inside another while loop which is different.. But why do you need two while loops, maybe you can do it without it.

Answer (score 1):

The second `while` loop is infinite, thus infinity never ends, so how do you expect it to go back to the outer while loop, so I think you meant:

```
c = 0
while True:   
    keyboard.write("t") 
    time.sleep(0.25)  
    c += 1            
    if not c % 2:
        keyboard.write("s")
        keyboard.write("e")
```

Your code only would work if you're Chunk Norris :) He can count to infinity twice :P

Comment: I'm sure this is not what the OP wants. Your code only executes `"t"` every `0.75` seconds.

Comment: @quamrana Edited my answer, should be fine now.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you think that different sections of code just run simultaneously without reference to each other. Unfortunately python is an imperative language, so each line executes before going on to the next.

You may have to collapse the loops into one and execute the `se` every other loop:

```py
import keyboard
import time
import itertools

for se in itertools.cycle((False, True)):   
        keyboard.write("t") 
        time.sleep(0.25)
        if se:
            keyboard.write("s")
            keyboard.write("e")
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it "unfortunate"... I'd be *devastated* if Python executed statements in random order or so :-)

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode: lol. You and me both. Its just unfortunate for the expectations of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I've added the following:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Process(target=t).start()
    Process(target=se).start()
```

This seems to have solved my issue

Comment: Ok, but this is very heavy-weight for what you need.

Comment: @quamrana Yeah, I think threads would suffice. But neither achieves the desired "all at the same time", as `sleep` isn't exact and the actions take different amounts of time, so the longer this runs, the less "at the same time" they'll happen.

Comment: This is an overkill...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked [add a full running code sample]. See How to Answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer